# My Eclipse Kepler cannot start

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler

My Eclipse Kepler is installed on Ubuntu. After I select the Eclipse icon either from folder or dash home, it displays a normal splash screen at the centre of my screen for a second, then the splash screen become totally a white (or gray?) rectangle. It's totally white, so I cannot see the progress of loading Eclipse, and no matter how long I wait, the splash screen hangs on and the workbench never appear.

NOTE: I incautiously deleted the ~/workspace directory, is this the cause of the problem?

Anyone know how to fix this problem?  :)

Comment: Hard to say what's your problem is. Try reinstalling it. Also google something like "installing Eclipse Kepler on Ubuntu". Like the following YouTube video (I'm not the author of it, just popped up in search): [Install Eclipse Kepler IDE for Java EE In Ubuntu 13.04](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7kR7a_Z9NIQ)

Comment: And also it would be more reasonable/relevant to ask such questions on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Try looking at the .log file, then editing your question to include that. The .log file is located in [workspace]/.metadata.
You may also want to look at [this](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t99010.html) page, which explains how to go about debugging a failed eclipse startup better than I can.

Comment: Sorry, I have already deleted my workspace as some threads say deleting workspace might help.

Comment: I tried but the workspace does not appear, it is really strange.

Comment: There might be another log file. Try going to `[eclipse installation directory]\Eclipse\configuration` and look for a *.log file.

Comment: I found the Configuration directory, but there is no .log file inside it. I can find a config.ini file and many directories named org.eclispe.****** .

Comment: OK. Sorry, but I can't help you any more than I already have.

Answer (score 0):

my solution - add below line to your eclipse.ini and restart.

-Djava.awt.headless=true

Answer (score 0):

in my case I ran the Eclipse with debug option 
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object

error came which meant the jdk did not work properly. 
I reinstalled jdk1.8 and set path for jdk\bin 
it worked fine